# How to convert a sub-range of a byte array to a String in C#

Tags: c#, string, arrays

In java, you can build a String from a sub-range of a byte[]. How can we perform a similar operation in C#?

Example java code:

```
byte[] buffer = ...
int offset    = ...
int length    = ...

String str = new String(buffer, offset, length);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` method has an overload to do this.

```
byte[] buffer = ... 
int offset    = ...
int length    = ...

String str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, length);
```